# Cleanest way to write a URL in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following code in my view, but it's pretty hard to read. I have read about the [Codeigniter url helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) and anchor(), but I can't seem to make it much cleaner in there either.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>games/<?php echo $row['slug']; ?>" title="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['title']; ?></a>
```

How can I clean this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the segments you require to the base_url() method, like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('games/'.$row['slug']) ?>" title="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['title']; ?></a>
```

This is cleaner and would give you the same result, however this might be a better option:

```
<?php echo anchor('games/'.$row['slug'], $row['title'], 'title="'.$row['title'].'"'); ?>
```

One tag, no need to declare PHP tags for each part that is dynamic and it takes care of the HTML output for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [*reverse routing*](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/DrF_Reverse_Routing).

This allows you to have one place to define routes which will propagate through all your existing website's links.